# MS Visio page size impossible to auto ajust

Tags: microsoft-visio

It is the first time I use MS Visio (2010) for making UML. Usually I used for other kind of shemes...

But this time I have a filligrane at the top (written "Structure statique") which make the page size grow on each *adjust size to draw* I perform... and I can not remove it because it is protected !

The growing of page might be a bug so if I can remove filligrane text I guess it should work.

Can you help me to remove it or to solve the bug ?

NOTE : I created the doc using the Visio template *UML - Model diagram*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's automatically added in the UML template
Source:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/visio-help/create-a-uml-sequence-diagram-HP001208871.aspx

You need to edit the template to not include it, as it looks like a bug in the template from here. I'd suggest viewing the background page and checking its orientation as a starting point.